# continuously passing events from main to renderer process

Tags: ipc, program-entry-point, electron, renderer

I've been using Electrons sync and async RPC communications mechanism and can pass my data between the processes quite nicely. However, I now need to continuously send event data (a bit like a chat application) to the renderer process and update some text.

Is this possible within electron? I'm guessing I'll need to create some kind of listener in the renderer process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`.

In main process.

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'example message...')
})
```

In renderer process (web page).

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  // arg contain your message (example message...)
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'example example send to main process')
```

you can also pass any object.

Comment: Thanks. Will this continually receive the events in the renderer process as long as the main process is sending them ?

Comment: like a stream ?

Comment: Yes - this exactly what I mean.

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know. I need check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it does. e.g.

Main Process:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain

ipc.on('asynchronous-message', function (event, arg) {
event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')

function countdown( elementName, minutes, seconds )
{
var element, endTime, hours, mins, msLeft, time;

function twoDigits( n )
{
  return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
}

function updateTimer()
{
  msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
  if ( msLeft < 1000 ) {
    //element.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'countdown is over')
  } else {
    time = new Date( msLeft );
    hours = time.getUTCHours();
    mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
    // element.innerHTML = (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() );
    event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', (hours ? hours + ':' + twoDigits( mins ) : mins) + ':' + twoDigits( time.getUTCSeconds() ));
    setTimeout( updateTimer, time.getUTCMilliseconds() + 500 );
  }
}

// element = document.getElementById( elementName );
endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60*minutes + seconds) + 500;
updateTimer();
}
countdown( "countdown", 1, 5 );
})
```

Renderer Process:

```
 const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

 ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
 // arg contain your message (example message...)
 })
 ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'example example send to main process')
```